# php date / time query on email header

Tags: php

I have a couple of dates on an email header:

```
[date] => Tue, 10 May 2016 03:13:24 -0700
[MailDate] => 10-May-2016 10:13:24 +0000
```

I received the email at 10:13am in my timezone.

```
$d=strtotime("10-May-2016 10:13:24 +0000");
echo "Created date is " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);
```

This is the output I get:

```
Created date is 2016-05-10 11:13:24am
```

Shouldn't this show the time as 10:13:24am?

Comment: You're setting the timezone with `+0000` - so no, it won't be guaranteed to be local to you unless you are setting it to *your* timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, there's nothing in that code that guarantees seeing 10:13:24 instead of 11:13:24.

**Why**

You are defining a timezone with `+0000`, so results are not guaranteed to be accurate. Even if your timezone is GMT (+0000), there's nothing in your script defining *your* timezone. The only thing that's present time-zone wise is the definition of *that string's* timezone.

Make sure your timezone is either permanently set in PHP, or temporarily in this script.

Change your php.ini (for a permanent change), or add a line to set your timezone before doing the date/time related functionality:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Try that before your script, and see what your script outputs. If all is setup correctly, you'll get the proper time.

Otherwise, you can always just remove the `+0000` from your `strtotime()` call.

Answer (score 0):

try without the `+0000` part:

`$d=strtotime("10-May-2016 10:13:24");
echo "Created date is " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);`